# MySQL Query too large, is there a way to opimize?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to optimize this large MySQL Query? I have tried many things, but they all give me results that are not correct, such as duplicates and empty columns.

```
SELECT quotations.*, 

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(groups.group_id, " | ", groups.group_name) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_groups`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(departments.department_id, " | ", departments.department_name, " | ", departments.department_code) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_departments`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(projects.project_id) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_projects`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(machines.machine_id, " | ", machines.machine_name) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_machines`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(parts.part_id, " | ", parts.part_name) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_parts`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(options.option_id, " | ", options.option_name) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_options`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(applications.application_id, " | ", applications.application_nl_title) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_applications`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(actions.action_id, " | ", actions.action_name) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_actions`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(tests.test_id, " | ", tests.test_name) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_tests`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(notes.note_id, " | ", notes.note_name) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_notes`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(companies.company_id, " | ", companies.company_name) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_companies`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(persons.person_id, " | ", persons.person_gender, " | ", persons.person_firstname, " | ", persons.person_middlename, " | ", persons.person_lastname, " | ", persons.person_function) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_persons`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(addresses.address_id, " | ", addresses.address_types, " | ", addresses.address_name, " | ", addresses.address_streetname, " | ", addresses.address_housenumber, " | ", addresses.address_zipcode, " | ", addresses.address_city) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_addresses`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(attachments.attachment_id, " | ", attachments.attachment_name) SEPARATOR " , ") AS `quotation_attachments` 

FROM quotations quotations 

LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_departments ON (quotation_departments.quotations_relations_child_name="departments" AND quotation_departments.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_groups ON (quotation_groups.quotations_relations_child_name="groups" AND quotation_groups.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_projects ON (quotation_projects.quotations_relations_child_name="projects" AND quotation_projects.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_machines ON (quotation_machines.quotations_relations_child_name="machines" AND quotation_machines.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_parts ON (quotation_parts.quotations_relations_child_name="parts" AND quotation_parts.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_options ON (quotation_options.quotations_relations_child_name="options" AND quotation_options.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_applications ON (quotation_applications.quotations_relations_child_name="applications" AND quotation_applications.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_actions ON (quotation_actions.quotations_relations_child_name="actions" AND quotation_actions.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_tests ON (quotation_tests.quotations_relations_child_name="tests" AND quotation_tests.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_notes ON (quotation_notes.quotations_relations_child_name="notes" AND quotation_notes.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_companies ON (quotation_companies.quotations_relations_child_name="companies" AND quotation_companies.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_persons ON (quotation_persons.quotations_relations_child_name="persons" AND quotation_persons.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_addresses ON (quotation_addresses.quotations_relations_child_name="addresses" AND quotation_addresses.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id)
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations quotation_attachments ON (quotation_attachments.quotations_relations_child_name="attachments" AND quotation_attachments.quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id) 

LEFT JOIN groups_relations groups_relations ON (groups_relations.groups_relations_child_name="quotations" AND groups_relations.groups_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN groups groups ON (groups.group_id=groups_relations.groups_relations_parent OR groups.group_id=quotation_groups.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN departments_relations departments_relations ON (departments_relations.departments_relations_child_name="quotations" AND departments_relations.departments_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN departments departments ON (departments.department_id=departments_relations.departments_relations_parent OR departments.department_id=quotation_departments.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN projects_relations projects_relations ON (projects_relations.projects_relations_child_name="quotations" AND projects_relations.projects_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN projects projects ON (projects.project_id=projects_relations.projects_relations_parent OR projects.project_id=quotation_projects.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN machines_relations machines_relations ON (machines_relations.machines_relations_child_name="quotations" AND machines_relations.machines_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN machines machines ON (machines.machine_id=machines_relations.machines_relations_parent OR machines.machine_id=quotation_machines.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN parts_relations parts_relations ON (parts_relations.parts_relations_child_name="quotations" AND parts_relations.parts_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN parts parts ON (parts.part_id=parts_relations.parts_relations_parent OR parts.part_id=quotation_parts.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN options_relations options_relations ON (options_relations.options_relations_child_name="quotations" AND options_relations.options_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN options options ON (options.option_id=options_relations.options_relations_parent OR options.option_id=quotation_options.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN applications_relations applications_relations ON (applications_relations.applications_relations_child_name="quotations" AND applications_relations.applications_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN applications applications ON (applications.application_id=applications_relations.applications_relations_parent OR applications.application_id=quotation_applications.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN actions_relations actions_relations ON (actions_relations.actions_relations_child_name="quotations" AND actions_relations.actions_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN actions actions ON (actions.action_id=actions_relations.actions_relations_parent OR actions.action_id=quotation_actions.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN tests_relations tests_relations ON (tests_relations.tests_relations_child_name="quotations" AND tests_relations.tests_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN tests tests ON (tests.test_id=tests_relations.tests_relations_parent OR tests.test_id=quotation_tests.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN notes_relations notes_relations ON (notes_relations.notes_relations_child_name="quotations" AND notes_relations.notes_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN notes notes ON (notes.note_id=notes_relations.notes_relations_parent OR notes.note_id=quotation_notes.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN companies_relations companies_relations ON (companies_relations.companies_relations_child_name="quotations" AND companies_relations.companies_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN companies companies ON (companies.company_id=companies_relations.companies_relations_parent OR companies.company_id=quotation_companies.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN persons_relations persons_relations ON (persons_relations.persons_relations_child_name="quotations" AND persons_relations.persons_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN persons persons ON (persons.person_id=persons_relations.persons_relations_parent OR persons.person_id=quotation_persons.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN addresses_relations addresses_relations ON (addresses_relations.addresses_relations_child_name="quotations" AND addresses_relations.addresses_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN addresses addresses ON (addresses.address_id=addresses_relations.addresses_relations_parent OR addresses.address_id=quotation_addresses.quotations_relations_child_id)
LEFT JOIN attachments_relations attachments_relations ON (attachments_relations.attachments_relations_child_name="quotations" AND attachments_relations.attachments_relations_child_id=quotations.quotation_id) 
LEFT JOIN attachments attachments ON (attachments.attachment_id=attachments_relations.attachments_relations_parent OR attachments.attachment_id=quotation_attachments.quotations_relations_child_id) 

GROUP BY quotations.quotation_id ORDER BY quotations.quotation_updated DESC
```

As you can see, i need to get all details from every table that have a relation with eachother.

I noticed, that, after a while, the more relations there are, the slower the query is, for example, i have this quotation with 103 relations, it takes up to 34seconds to gather all data.

Comment: *I noticed, that, after a while, the more relations there are, the slower the query is* Uh, did you expect it to run faster when you asked it to do more stuff?

Comment: Isn't there a SELECT * FROM * GROUP BY * in mysql? =P

Comment: Sure... But 34 seconds!? it went from 0.2 seconds with 10 relations to 34seconds with 103 relations.

Comment: Two big words: combinatorial explosion.

Comment: Can we have a look on the tables schema?

Comment: @xpy It is really too big to display. But look @ my SELECT to have a view of what i need from other tables.

Comment: I am talking about the schema, not the data, is it really that big?

Comment: @xpy Here is is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1RL3Y-XWhbpcy1pa0QzaGlDTVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: do you really need ALL the details from EVERY table?  Normal practice is to pull only what you're currently accessing/displaying.  If you can cut back on what you're pulling back, and use only that information, that will likely help your performance significantly.  Standard practice is to query up only what you need for whatever you're doing at the moment, and create a separate query for each type of data retrieval (if that means that you have to write a couple dozen queries, then that's what it is).

Comment: So, there may be two relations between e.g. `groups` and `quotations`, one in `groups_relations` and one in `quotation_relations` both meaning the same thing?

Comment: Indeed, i can make a connection from groups to quotations with groups_relations and make a connection from quotations to groups with quotations_relations.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to do a single `join` with conditional aggregation.  You will probably not need the `DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT()` any more.  Here is an example for departments:

```
SELECT q.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN qr.quotations_relations_child_name = 'departments' THEN qr.department_id, ' | ', qr.department_name END)
FROM quotations q LEFT JOIN
     quotations_relations qr
     ON qr.quotations_relations_parent = q.quotation_id
GROUP BY q.quotation_id
ORDER BY q.quotation_updated DESC ;
```

Comment: To keep it easy for me and all other modules i want to stay using one query to gather all data i need, or are you saying i cant have an optimized query like this to collect all required data from all relations?

Comment: That's not "keeping it easy", that's pulling back a bunch of stuff you're not using and flushing a bunch of performance down the drain.

Comment: @LionH . . . You can just add more `GROUP_CONCAT()` expressions for each of the lists that you want.  You don't need another `join` (at least to `quotations_rlations`).

Comment: Sorry Gordon Linoff i dont understand what you mean. in both, quotations_relations and groups_relations, there can be a relation with eachother. So i must look into both tables.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you please reply?

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you could use only one join for the quotations:

```
LEFT JOIN quotations_relations ON quotations_relations_parent=quotations.quotation_id
```

and do the relation check on the individual rows:
e.g.

```
LEFT JOIN groups groups ON 
(
groups.group_id=groups_relations.groups_relations_parent OR 
(groups.group_id=quotations_relations.quotations_relations_child_id AND quotations_relations_child_name="groups")
)
```